# How do I let other meeting participants know what company I represent?

Tags: microsoft-teams

In a Teams meeting with external participants it helps a lot if you can see what company or organization each person represent and what role they have. Can I fill out this information somewhere in the Teams account settings so that my company and role shows by default whenever I participate in a meeting? Something like "My Name / Software Developer / My Company" instead of just "My Name".

I use Microsoft Teams version 24004.1307.2669.7070.

Comment: For the record, Teams is an awful tool for doing external meetings. It's intended for internal *Teams* of people. Frame challenge, why don't you use Zoom instead?

Comment: @Valorum Even within a larger organization it would be helpful to know the team and role of each person.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Within a *single* larger organization, you should be able to see the job title and org chart in the hover popup (at least you can in the Teams desktop app and Outlook web). That's not available for "external" users. I agree that Zoom is better for external matters, though it's not like you have the power to switch unless you're high up in your organization.